# Dockerizing .NET Core Web Api

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm trying to dockerize .NET Core 2.x web api application for the first time.
Here are my files:

### **Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 AS build-env

WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
RUN dotnet ef database update

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "docker-webapi.dll"]
```

### **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

# define all containers we want to use
services:
  db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    # define the credentials to be used in our web application
    environment: 
        ACCEPT_EULA: 'Y'
        SA_PASSWORD: 'sa12345$'
    ports:
        - '1433:1433'
  web:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: docker-webapi
    depends_on: 
        - db
    ports:
        - '3000:3000'
```

### **appsettings.json**

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "User ID=sa;password=sa12345$;server=db;Database=master"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

### **From Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
}
```

Whenever I try to build, using any of the following commands:

```
docker-compose build .
or
docker build -t docker-webapi .
```

I get the error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught) ---> 
System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 6): No such device or address
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your connection-string has `server=db`. Shouldn't it be `server=(local)`?

Comment: Actually db is the name of database service from docker-compose, should it be (local) for docker as well?

Comment: `System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 6): No such device or address` It is definitely a service discovery issue.

Comment: So the issue is the database connection (SQL server isn't accessible through the network), not the Web API itself. Is the SQL server running in a separate container?

Comment: No, sql server is not running separately as defined in docker-compose

Comment: Maybe related to expose your db to 1433 port. Don't expose and try again.